# Am I correctly using the word "interest"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> The professor hoped to *interest* his students in English grammar.
>
> His explanations were so *interesting* that all the students *interested in*.

Are the words which I have put in italics correctly used in these sentences?

Comment: *His explanations were so interesting that all the students were/got/became interested in (them).*

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to have figured out, *interest* can be used as a verb (*to arouse the curiosity of*) or as a noun (*a feeling of wanting to know more about something*).<sup>1</sup>

A professor can use either form to express his hope:

> As a professor I hope to interest my students in English grammar.   (*verb*)
> As a professor I hope to increase my students' interest in English grammar. (*noun*)
> As a professor I hope my students experience an increased interest in English grammar. (*noun*)

All of those are grammatical, but I'm not sure any of them represent how I'd express that sentiment. I think these two options sound more natural to my ear:

> As a professor I hope my students become more interested in English grammar.
> As a professor I hope my students find English grammar more and more interesting.

That said, the verb usage is acceptable, and the word **does** get used that way:

> As a professor of English I feel it my duty to interest my students in the literature of all periods. (from *Journal of Canadian Fiction*, 1973)

This sentence of yours does need some work, though:

> His explanations were so interesting that all the students interested in.

Specifically, we need a verb before *interested in,* and an object after it. For example:

> His explanations were so interesting that all the students **became** interested in **the subject**.
> His explanations were so interesting that all the students **remained** interested in **his lectures**.
> His explanations were so interesting that all the students **found themselves** interested in **the topic**.

We could also change the preposition:

> His explanations were so interesting that all the students **stayed** interested **until the bell rang**.

---

<sup>1</sup>Definitions 1 & 10 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interest) are paraphrased in parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your concern comes from the financial meaning of the word "interest".
The word “interest” has also a meaning of: attention, concern, curiosity, importance, etc.
As a result, the usage of “interest” is correct in your examples.
Regarding the third example, to be correct it should have a verb before: “were/got/became” like in Damkerng T comment.

Comment: The third usage is actually incorrect, as far as I can see. ("...all the students *interested in*.") Would you mind addressing that point? That would be a verb form of the word I literally haven't seen before. (I know, I don't get out much.)

Comment: I thought the verb "were" was omitted. If not so, you are right the usage is not correct.

Comment: Ahh. That would make sense. Perhaps the OP can clarify. "...that all the students [were] interested in [the subject]" would be much more reasonable.

Comment: What makes you think that the financial meaning of _interest_ has anything to do with this question? Nothing in the question would lead me to make that assumption (in fact, I'd assume the opposite).

Comment: Actually I can’t produce any plausible evidence to sustain my assumption. This was once my concern and I thought it was his, too. Obviously it has nothing to do with the subject. It was proved I was wrong.